# A convergent sequence is bounded: Proof Verification

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

May you please verify my proof. I feel like I am not being rigorous, and assuming that the infimum and the supremum are finite.

**Theorem**: A convergent sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ is bounded.

**Proof**:

Let $l\in \Bbb R$ such that $a_n \rightarrow l$.

Then $\forall \epsilon>0\,,\exists n_0\in \Bbb N;\forall n \in \Bbb N,\, n\ge n_0 \implies|a_n-l|<\epsilon $

Let $\epsilon=Max\{|sup((a_n)_{n\in \Bbb N})|, \, |inf((a_n)_{n\in \Bbb N})|\}$,

Then $|a_n-l|<\epsilon\,\,\,\,\forall n\in \Bbb N\,\,$

Then $l-\epsilon<a_n<l+\epsilon\,\,\, \forall n\in \Bbb N$

So $(a_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ is bounded.

I know the classical proof of this, but I was wondering if this workes too! Any helps is greately appreciated!

Comment: If you assume the supremum and infinum to be finite, you've immediately assumed the sequence is bounded. So unfortunately this proof doesn't work.

Comment: Why should $\text{Max}\{|\sup((a_n)_{n\in \Bbb N})|, \, |\inf((a_n)_{n\in \Bbb N})|\}$ be a real number?  Don't you need boundedness?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! I knew I there was something circular about this. Upvote to both your comments. @bitesizebo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume it is not bounded. Then
$$(\forall n\in \Bbb N) \;\; (\exists \phi (n) \in \Bbb N)\;:$$
$$|a_{\phi (n)}|>n $$

thus $b_n=a_{\phi (n)} $ will be a divergent subsequence of a convergent one.